# works in postman but python request failing error":"Invalid access token

Tags: python, api, client

scratching my head around this simple code giving error 401:invalid access token. could it be due to some endpoint security software tampering the request? code is actually generated by postman, believe no issue with it!

```
    import requests

    url = "<url>"

    payload = {}
    headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>',
  'Cookie': 'xxxx'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok. Maybe the problem is with the token you provide.
Check on https://jwt.io/ if you token is expired.
Paste you token on the input field and then check the payload. If there is a `exp`, take that timestamp and paste it on google to convert it to locale date time.

Comment: ty. token is fine. testing simultaneously from postman and python code.

Comment: What is the API you are trying to call?

Answer (score 0):

sorry it was ipaddr restriction! once i removed it , code worked fine. that error was misleading though. thanks.